# Unable to produce more than half the array once i converted char to string

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently trying to create an array that has 26 elements and initialising to characters 'a' to 'z'. However when i run my code, i am unable to get the output of all the elements and only half of them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Alphabet{
private:
    string name;

public:
    void setName(string name){
        this->name=name;
    }
    void speak(){
        cout << name << endl;
    }
};


int main() {

    Alphabet *pAlphabet = new Alphabet[26];
    char start = 'a';

    for(int i=0;i<26;i++,start++,pAlphabet++){
        string copy(1,start);
        pAlphabet[i].setName(copy);
        pAlphabet[i].speak();

    }


    return 0;
```

Comment: `pAlphabet++` is definitely not something you want to have in your loop (because you are already using `i` to index into the array). Why did you add that?

Answer (score 4):

You loop is incrementing too much and too many

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++,start++,pAlphabet++){
    string copy(1,start);
    pAlphabet[i].setName(copy);
    pAlphabet[i].speak();

}
```

Before the loop `pAlphabet` points to the first element of a 26-sized array of `Alphabet`s. `pAlphabet[i]` is the same as `*(pAlphabet + i)`, ie it increments the pointer by `i` and dereferences it to get the element at position `i`.

When you increment `i` and `pAlphabet` then in the second iteration you have `pAlphabet[i] == *(pointer_to_first_element + 1 + 0 + 1) == *(pointer_to_first_element + 2)`.

In the 14-th iteration you have already incremented `i` and `pAlphabet` each 13 times and try to access `*(pointer_to_first_element + 26)` which is out-of-bounds, because the array has only 26 elements and the last valid index is `25`.

Do not use c-arrays. Use a `std::array` or `std::vector` and range based for loops:

```
std::vector<Alphabet> vAlphabet(26);
char c = 'a';
for (auto& a : vAlphabet) {
      a.setName(std::string(1,c));
      ++c;
      a.speak();
}
```

---

PS: It is not clear what the purpose of your code is. I suppose it is for learning. Part of learning is to learn how to keep things simple. If you merely need an array with all letters from `'a'` till `'z'` I would use

```
std::string alphabet{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
```

Comment: Typo `auot` -> `auto`